# How to insert GMap macro to a page in Drupal with Gmap module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I created a GMap macro but I do not know how to insert it on the page. When I try to put it in the body field of a page, it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the GMap macro filter turned on in your input format of choice?

For example, if you edit Full HTML, it should have a list of options like HTML Filter, Link Filter, etc. When you enable Gmap on the input format, it can then parse those macros.

Comment: Where would these options be located? Thanks!